# Android - XMLPullParser not parsing entire file

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xmlpullparser

I am a beginner and am having a lot of difficulties with parsing an XML from a website.

Here is the code to parse the XML after it has been downloaded into a file:

```
public RSSFeed readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    RSSFeed feed = new RSSFeed();
    RSSLocation location = new RSSLocation();
    RSSTime time = new RSSTime();
    XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
    InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);

    try {
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, true);
        parser.setInput(inputStream,null);

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                // yweather:forecast - forecast is name of the element, yweather is namespace
                Log.d("Parser Name", parser.getName());
                Log.d("Parser Text", parser.getText());
                Log.d("Parser Desc", parser.getPositionDescription());
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("XML Parser", e.toString());
    }

    return feed;
}
```

Here is the XML file: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=40.2845939&lon=-75.6475172&mode=xml&cnt=3&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0

I am simply trying to see how the data is being parsed so I can then appropriately assign the objects and their attributes.

I just want to see in the log what is returned based on each method (getName(), getText(), getAttributeValue()...)

However, when I use the above code to send the information to the log, it is only getting the first tag `<weatherdata>` and returning a NullPointerException: println needs a message for the Text.

Here is the logcat:

```
12-06 14:52:30.009 17507-17557/com.example.shortn1.whattowear E/XML Parser: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
12-06 14:52:30.049 17507-17507/com.example.shortn1.whattowear D/Weather Feed: Feed displayed
12-06 14:52:50.849 17507-17554/com.example.shortn1.whattowear D/Parser Name: weatherdata
12-06 14:52:50.849 17507-17554/com.example.shortn1.whattowear E/XML Parser: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
12-06 14:52:50.889 17507-17507/com.example.shortn1.whattowear D/Weather Feed: Feed displayed
12-06 14:53:10.874 17507-17856/com.example.shortn1.whattowear D/Parser Name: weatherdata
12-06 14:53:10.874 17507-17856/com.example.shortn1.whattowear E/XML Parser: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
12-06 14:53:10.919 17507-17507/com.example.shortn1.whattowear D/Weather Feed: Feed displayed
12-06 14:53:30.809 17507-17557/com.example.shortn1.whattowear D/Parser Name: weatherdata
12-06 14:53:30.809 17507-17557/com.example.shortn1.whattowear E/XML Parser: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
12-06 14:53:30.839 17507-17507/com.example.shortn1.whattowear D/Weather Feed: Feed displayed
```

My main activity is too long to post here, but there is a location finder and in onLocationChanged() the method is called to download the xml corresponding to the person's location. Once the file is returned, the `readFile()` method is called. After the file is read, another method is called (which is logging "Feed displayed").

I also tried changing the XML Parser to only grab the "name" field from the XML by adding `&& parser.getName().equals("name")` but it still only reads the word 'name' and does not return the value of the name.

Any suggestions? All help is appreciated!! Thank you ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is related to the `Log.d`, both of its paramaters must be different than `null` and non empty. It seems that `parser.getText()` is returning `null` which causes the `Exception` and the end of the `while` loop (that is the reason why it only outputs the first tag).

Try doing this:

```
String name = parser.getName();
String text = parser.getText();
String positionDescription = parser.getPositionDescription();

Log.d("Parser Name", name != null && !name.equals("") ? name : "---");
Log.d("Parser Text", text != null && !text.equals("") ? text : "---");
Log.d("Parser Desc", positionDescription != null && !positionDescription.equals("") ? positionDescription : "---");
```

This should output the rest of the document, everytime that one of the parser methods returns `null` or empty then the output will be `---`.

**EDIT**

To get the text inside the tags you'll have to change your code to:

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
{
    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
    {
        String name = parser.getName();
        String positionDescription = parser.getPositionDescription();

        Log.d("Parser Name", name != null && !name.equals("") ? name : "---");
    }
    else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
    {
        String text = parser.getText();
        Log.d("Parser Text", text != null && !text.equals("") ? text : "---");
    }
    eventType = parser.next();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This has allowed the parser to go through the entire document; however, none of the values are being found? Do you know why this is?

Comment: Hm... from what I'm getting from your comment you haven't fully understand how the `XmlPullParser`, you can have a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html <-- for example here you can see that the `getText()` method will only return something if the `eventType` is `TEXT` and it has something to return

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what I'm missing. The example XML reads:
`<name>Location Name</name>`
if `getName()` returns 'name' , shouldn't `.getText()` return 'Location Name' ?

Comment: see the edited answer, try that, according to the docs you should get the content of the tag

Comment: Okay! I see now! `eventType` of start_tag and text are separate. Thank you. Much appreciated.